# ¿Por qué se utiliza el subjuntivo en oraciones del tipo: "antes de que finalizara"?

Tags: subjuntivo

En oraciones como

> Antes de que el partido finalizara, los hinchas dejaron el estadio.

me pregunto:

- ¿Por qué se utiliza el subjuntivo?
- ¿Es éste es un tipo especial del mismo?

Comment: Tu pregunta se refiere a porqué se utiliza o si es un tipo especial de subjuntivo?

Comment: Quizá ayude que nos expliques por qué te sorprende que se use en esas oraciones.

Comment: No veo ningunos usos del subjuntivo en el ejemplo anterior... Entonces, qué quieres decir?

Comment: @Noldorin *finalizara* stands *finalizar*, in *subjuntivo pretérito*. Perhaps you didn't recognize it because *finalizar* has two options to build that tense: *finalizase* and *finalizara.*

Comment: Bueno, es una cosa de curiosidad. Segun tengo entendido el subjuntivo se utiliza en peticiones, deseos, exigencias, etc, ademas de expresar una realidad hipotetica, por lo tanto, me pregunto por que se utiliza aqui si el ejemplo dado no se adecua a ninguna de las funciones del subjuntivo, al menos que yo conozca.

Comment: @c.p. Ah yes, so it is... I read it quickly and it looked like the future tense. I assume readers are lazy like me with putting the accents on. :)

Comment: @Noldorin Not in this forum, I hope :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tras un poco de investigación gramática, mis descubrimientos fueron los siguientes:

- Se usa el subjuntivo con "antes de" y "después de", si se trata de diferentes sujetos ("comimos antes de que lloviera" vs. "comí antes de salir"). Una lista completa de usos [acá](http://uni.canuelo.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/subjuntivo_formas_y_usos_nvo.pdf).
- Se usa porque al momento de la acción del presente (comer), el futuro (llover) aún es hipotético.

Comment: Creo que con el segundo punto has dado en la clave.

Comment: Cuidado, porque *después de que* no siempre implica subjuntivo.  «Comimos después de que llovió» por ejemplo, o en situaciones habituales como «Todos los días después de que suena mi despertador, me levanto»